# Add one space before each English word after Chinese characters

Tags: languages, letterspacing

I often mix English words in my Chinese texts.  When doing that, I want to add a space before the English words.  For example:

```
XXXX wwwww wwwww wwwww XXXX
    *
```

where X's are Chinese characters and w's are English letters.

The only problem is the space marked *, where the Chinese characters end and the English words start.  Latex seems to swallow up that space, but I want it to be there.

Is there an automatic command that can handle this?

PS:  right now my solution is to manually add a space by '\ ' whenever I insert English.

Comment: more information would be helpful.  for example, what document class and packages.  the answer will be found in them.

Comment: Please add a [Minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: Thanks, but I found the solution.. see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found that my problem is gone when I run XeLatex in TexMaker with this:

```
\documentclass[12pt, UTF8, nofonts]{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}
```

I used the pdfLatex command and apparently, it is not good at handling some subtleties of Asian texts.  Now the space between English and Chinese texts is added automatically.